# Calculating profit and loss in php/mysql for sales application (Daily, Monthly and Yearly)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a challenge in php/mysql, that i can not clearly get a solution about it, i have three tables items table, sales_orders table, sales_order_details.

```
items table (Entities)
stockId | branchId | itemName | itemQuantity | buyingPrice

sales_orders table (Entities)
| orderId | orderNo | branchId | orderDate | total

sales_order_details (Entities)
sales_order_detailsId | orderId | stockId | sellingPrice | orderedQuantity
```

I want to calculate profit and loss of the store sales that will be shown e.g for today profit

```
Today profit = Tshs. 780,000
```

I have tried the below query but i don't get true value

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT
 Sum(sales_order_details.quantity) AS Quantity,
 SUM(sales_order_details.price) AS price,
 SUM((SELECT SUM(buyingPrice) from items INNER JOIN sales_order_details ON items.stockId = sales_order_details.stockId WHERE sales_order_details.orderId = sales_orders.orderId)) AS buyingPrice
 FROM 
 sales_orders 
 JOIN sales_order_details
 ON 
 sales_orders.orderId = sales_order_details.orderId 
 WHERE 
 DATE(sales_orders.orderDate)='date("Y-m-d")' 
 AND 
 sales_orders.branchId =1 
 AND 
 salesStatus=1");
$total_expenses1=0;
$total1=0;$total2=0;
while ($row31=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $qty = $row31['Quantity'];
  $priceb = $row31['buyingPrice'];
  $prices = $row31['price'];
  $total1 = $qty * ($prices - $priceb);
  $total_expenses1 =$total1;
}
?>
<div class="row">
  <?php
    $total_expenses = $total_expenses1-$today_expenses;
    if ($total_expenses>0) {
  ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 ">Today Profit </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 bg-success"><?php echo $row['currencyName'].". ".number_format($total_expenses, 2)?></div>
  <?php
   }elseif($total_expenses<0){
 ?>
<div class="col-md-4 ">Today Loss </div>
<div class="col-md-8 bg-danger"><?php echo $row['currencyName'].". ".number_format($total_expenses, 2)?></div>
<?php
}else{
?>
<div class="col-md-4 ">Today </div>
<div class="col-md-8 bg-primary"><?php echo $row['currencyName'].". ".number_format($total_expenses, 2)?></div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

All the examples i can see online, i can not get answer to this problem.
Thank you in advance for any thought or assistance to this.

Comment: The `'date("Y-m-d")'` doesn't seem to be a valid part of a MySQL query, it looks like PHP. I think you mean to use [CURDATE()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_curdate.asp)? I also seem to miss the actual call to execute the query.

Comment: What have you tried to debug where this goes wrong? Have you tried to use the SQL query directly on the database (using Workbench or phpMyAdmin or something else) to see whether the query works?

Comment: Incidentally, we normally use $query for the query and $result for the result. You've used $query for the result. Makes no difference, but I would have been curious to see the echo for the query, had it existed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your query:

```
SELECT Sum(d.quantity) Quantity
     , SUM(d.price) price
     , SUM(
            (SELECT SUM(buyingPrice) 
               FROM items i
               JOIN sales_order_details d
                 ON i.stockId = d.stockId 
              WHERE d.orderId = o.orderId
             )
           ) buyingPrice 
  FROM sales_orders o
  JOIN sales_order_details d
    ON o.orderId = d.orderId 
 WHERE DATE(sales_orders.orderDate) = DATE_FORMAT(now(),"%Y-%m-%d")  -- changed this line
   AND o.branchId = 1 
   AND salesStatus = 1
```

Comment: who give negative plz explain the case.

Comment: thank you, but still the query gives me the same answer

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but my guess, as to the reason, is that you don't explain anything in your answer. You don't even say what issue you have found. It is also clear that your answer doesn't solve the real problem, even before Edgar Inga said so.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, thank you for the kind reply. But I have specified, that the query was written in php which is not working in mysql query.

Comment: Just saying "changed this line", without any explanation as to why, isn't enough. These answers might stay online for years, thousands of people will read them, and the first question, they have, hasn't been answered: "Why this change?". So besides simply "answering" the question, your answer must inform people. That's the whole idea behind StackOverflow: Sharing knowledge. Just like you demand an explanation for the negative vote, is it too much to explain your answer?